# Remove Column Header into the Output Text file

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, spool, columnheader

I want to create a flat file (text file) of my query from Oracle SQL Developer.

I have successfully created the text file using SPOOL, thru a script text file, but i want to remove the header of each column into my output.

I am getting this output:

```
Header000001 Header000002
------------ ------------
Adetail1     Bdetail1
Adetail2     Bdetail2
Adetail3     Bdetail3
```

But, I want to get this output:

```
Adetail1Bdetail1
Adetail2Bdetail2
Adetail3Bdetail3
```

I already tried the command "set heading off", but a message says:

```
"SQLPLUS COMMAND Skipped: set heading off".
```

These are the inputs I've issued:

```
spool on; 
spool C:\SQLFiles\PSB_ATMLKP.txt; 
set newpage 0; 
set echo off; 
set feedback off; 
set heading off; 

select terminal_number, terminal_name from terminal_table; 

spool off;
```

Comment: Could you give us all commands you've issued and in which order?

Comment: <pre>
spool on;
spool C:\SQLFiles\PSB_ATMLKP.txt;
set newpage 0;
set echo off;
set feedback off;
set heading off;
select terminal_number, terminal_name
from terminal_table;
spool off;
</pre>

Comment: I've edited them into your question for you.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> SQLPLUS COMMAND Skipped: set heading off

That message is most likely because you are not executing it through `SQL*Plus`, but some GUI based tool. You are using SQLPlus command in SQL Developer. Not all SQL*Plus commands are guaranteed to work with **SQL Developer**.

I would suggest you execute the script in **SQLPlus** and you would see no issues.

You need:

```
SET HEADING OFF
```

This will not include the column headers in the output.

Alternatively, you could also do this:

```
SET PAGESIZE 0
```

**Using SQL Developer Version 3.2.20.10**:

```
spool ON
spool D:\test.txt
SET heading OFF
SELECT ename FROM emp;
spool off
```

[image]

Spool file got created with no issues:

```
> set heading OFF
> SELECT ename FROM emp
SMITH      
ALLEN      
WARD       
JONES      
MARTIN     
BLAKE      
CLARK      
SCOTT      
KING       
TURNER     
ADAMS      
JAMES      
FORD       
MILLER     

 14 rows selected
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My version is 2.1.1.64.

Comment: Then perhaps you could use SQL*Plus rather than SQL Developer. Or upgrade your SQL Developer. Please mark it answered if it has helped you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The poster asked how to do this using SQL Developer.

Comment: @TerribleTadpole I think you haven't read complete answer. I have clearly shown how to do it in SQL Developer. OP has marked it as an answer too.

Answer (score 6):

Add:

```
set underline off
```

to the beginning of the SQL script.

In my SQL scripts I have:

```
SET TERMOUT OFF
set colsep |
set pagesize 0 
set trimspool on
set pagesize  0 embedded on
SET heading on
SET UNDERLINE OFF
spool file_path
-- your SQL here
spool off
```

See [this book](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/oracle-sqlplus-the/0596007469/re105.html) for reference.

Comment: useful if you want headlines, but no underline. Otherwise, if you prefer just results, setting heading off will suffice. That is: 'SET heading OFF'

Answer (score 0):

A full exmple.
The trick is sqlplus -s

```
 sqlplus -s / as sysdba <<EOF
> SET TERMOUT OFF
> SET LINESIZE 1000
>  set echo off;
> set feedback off;
> set heading off;
> spool /tmp/killSession${esquema}.sql
> select 'alter system kill session'||' ''' || s.sid||','||s.serial# ||''' IMMEDIATE;'
> from v\$session s, v\$process p
> where s.username = '${esquema}'
> and p.addr (+) = s.paddr;
> EOF

alter system kill session '598,60705' IMMEDIATE;
alter system kill session '13,6279' IMMEDIATE;
alter system kill session '595,49129' IMMEDIATE;
alter system kill session '591,46591' IMMEDIATE;
alter system kill session '16,47283' IMMEDIATE;
alter system kill session '403,34455' IMMEDIATE;
alter system kill session '604,37015' IMMEDIATE;

[oracle@nominabdf ~]$ more /tmp/killSession${esquema}.sql

alter system kill session '598,60705' IMMEDIATE;



alter system kill session '13,6279' IMMEDIATE;



alter system kill session '595,49129' IMMEDIATE;



alter system kill session '591,46591' IMMEDIATE;



alter system kill session '16,47283' IMMEDIATE;



alter system kill session '403,34455' IMMEDIATE;



alter system kill session '604,37015' IMMEDIATE;
```